# Convert Video to MP3

Tags: android

**I want to Convert Video(mp4) to Mp3 format. Please if any one know then explain me.**

**I have tried this but its not working.**

I have implement from this link but it wont work for me. 
[How do I extractor audio to mp3 from mp4 using java in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692269/how-do-i-extractor-audio-to-mp3-from-mp4-using-java-in-android)

```
public class AudioFromVideo  {

    private String audio, video;
    private MediaCodec amc;
    private MediaExtractor ame;
    private MediaFormat amf;
    private String amime;

    public AudioFromVideo(String srcVideo, String destAudio) {
        this.audio = destAudio;
        this.video = srcVideo;
        ame = new MediaExtractor();
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        try {
            ame.setDataSource(video);
            amf = ame.getTrackFormat(1);
            ame.selectTrack(1);
            amime = amf.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            amc = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(amime);
            amc.configure(amf, null, null, 0);
            amc.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        new AudioService(amc, ame, audio).start();
    }

    private class AudioService extends Thread {
        private MediaCodec amc;
        private MediaExtractor ame;
        private ByteBuffer[] aInputBuffers, aOutputBuffers;
        private String destFile;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        AudioService(MediaCodec amc, MediaExtractor ame, String destFile) {
            this.amc = amc;
            this.ame = ame;
            this.destFile = destFile;
            aInputBuffers = amc.getInputBuffers();
            aOutputBuffers = amc.getOutputBuffers();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void run() {
            try {
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(destFile));
                long count = 0;
                while (true) {
                    int inputIndex = amc.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
                    if (inputIndex == -1) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    int sampleSize = ame.readSampleData(aInputBuffers[inputIndex], 0);
                    if (sampleSize == -1) break;
                    long presentationTime = ame.getSampleTime();
                    int flag = ame.getSampleFlags();
                    ame.advance();
                    amc.queueInputBuffer(inputIndex, 0, sampleSize, presentationTime, flag);
                    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                    int outputIndex = amc.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 0);
                    if (outputIndex >= 0) {
                        byte[] data = new byte[info.size];
                        aOutputBuffers[outputIndex].get(data, 0, data.length);
                        aOutputBuffers[outputIndex].clear();
                        os.write(data);
                        count += data.length;
                        Log.e("write", "" + count);
                        amc.releaseOutputBuffer(outputIndex, false);
                    } else if (outputIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                        aOutputBuffers = amc.getOutputBuffers();
                    } else if (outputIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                    }
                }
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> new AudioFromVideo(videopath,audioPath).start();

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "its not working" and "it wont work for me" means.

Comment: What is not working? Explain in detail

Comment: it will give me nullpointer at aInputBuffers = amc.getInputBuffers(); this line

Comment: can anyone help me to convert mp3 into mp4 ?(audio to video conversion) and there will be image which i have to display in video ... i cannot post a question and i am in need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to extract Audio from Mp4 Videos using Android FFmpeg Library:

ffmpeg -i my_video.mp4  -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn my_audio.mp3

Here is link to the library that does this:

http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

http://www.android-arsenal.com/details/1/931

Comment: read [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) post code part .. external link may not be forever.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to extract audio form vidoe file in android programmatically. You can do this without using any external library. It can be done by using MediaMuxer class.

```
new AudioExtractor().genVideoUsingMuxer("Video source Path", "Audio destination path", -1, -1, true, false);
```

See this post fro better understanding and complete code.

https://androidprogrammatically425516919.wordpress.com/2020/04/21/how-to-convert-video-to-audio-in-android-programmatically/